# @RequestHeader using parameter-names - how to escape?

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, request-headers

Since http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/118 its possible to access the parameter-names of methods.

In spring we could write

```
 @GetMapping("/rest/file/{id}")
 public void get(@PathVariable long id) {...
```

To access the id in the url.

For HttpHeaders a similar functionality exists:

```
 @GetMapping("/rest/files")
 public void get(@RequestHeader String Host) {...
```

To access the Host-request-header.

What about escaping? What if we have a request-header that is not matching java naming conventions? For a ETag we can not use this:

```
 @GetMapping("/rest/files")
 public void get(@RequestHeader(required=false) String If-None-Match) {...
```

Because `-` is not allowed for a name.

How to escape `-` in the header?

### Using escape parameter-names only!!!

Comment: you can also autowire HttpHeaders instead if its creating issue for you.  
ref: https://justamonad.com/injecting-headers-in-spring-rest-controller-requestheader/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to provide header `name` as parameter to `@RequestHeader`?

```
@GetMapping("/rest/files")
 public void get(@RequestHeader(required=false, name ="If-None-Match") String ifNoneMatch) {.
```

Comment: Title contains `using parameter-names`